# Informix Siblings - Table with repeated Values

Tags: informix, siblings

I try to get a result like this:

> 10 Pos 1 = 20
>
> ---------------Pos 1
>
> ---------------Pos 2 = 50
>
> ---------------------------Pos 1
> Pos 2 = 30
>
> Pos 3 = 40
>
> ---------------Pos 1
>
> ---------------Pos 2

```
CREATE TABLE beispiel (
    fa INTEGER,
    fa_pos integer,
    verurs INTEGER,
    verurs_pos INTEGER,
    auftrag INTEGER
);

INSERT INTO beispiel VALUES (   10  ,   1   ,   24548   ,   1   ,   24548   );
INSERT INTO beispiel VALUES (   10  ,   2   ,   24548   ,   1   ,   24548   );
INSERT INTO beispiel VALUES (   10  ,   3   ,   24548   ,   1   ,   24548   );
INSERT INTO beispiel VALUES (   20  ,   1   ,   10  ,   1   ,   24548   );
INSERT INTO beispiel VALUES (   20  ,   2   ,   10  ,   1   ,   24548   );
INSERT INTO beispiel VALUES (   30  ,   0   ,   10  ,   2   ,   24548   );
INSERT INTO beispiel VALUES (   40  ,   1   ,   10  ,   3   ,   24548   );
INSERT INTO beispiel VALUES (   40  ,   2   ,   10  ,   3   ,   24548   );
INSERT INTO beispiel VALUES (   50  ,   1   ,   20  ,   2   ,   24548   );
```

I run this statement:

```
SELECT 
LEVEL, sys_connect_by_path(fa, "/") AS pfad, 
fa, fa_pos, verurs, verurs_pos

FROM beispiel

CONNECT BY PRIOR fa = verurs

GROUP BY LEVEL,fa, pfad, fa_pos, verurs, verurs_pos
ORDER siblings BY verurs
```

Result:

```
   level    pfad    fa  fa_pos  verurs  verurs_pos
1   /10 10  1   24548   1
2   /10/20  20  2   10  1
2   /10/20  20  1   10  1
3   /10/20/50   50  1   20  2
2   /10/30  30  0   10  2
1   /40 40  1   10  3
1   /50 50  1   20  2
1   /20 20  1   10  1
1   /30 30  0   10  2
2   /10/40  40  1   10  3
1   /10 10  3   24548   1
1   /10 10  2   24548   1
2   /10/40  40  2   10  3
2   /20/50  50  1   20  2
1   /20 20  2   10  1
1   /40 40  2   10  3
```

Why do I get as result /50? How can I ignore this value?
And I get duplicated values and the Tree doesn´t look like a Child --> Parent --> Grandparent Structure.

Do I really need to do a GROUP BY?

Any idea?

I need to get an ordered result with siblings.

Answer (score 1):

You can modify the `CONNECT BY` clause and use the `CONNECT_BY_ROOT` function in your SQL query. Additionally, you can use the `ORDER SIBLINGS BY` clause to order the result by specific columns. Here's the modified SQL query:

```
SELECT 
  LEVEL,
  SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH(fa, "/") AS pfad,
  CONNECT_BY_ROOT(fa) AS root_fa,
  CONNECT_BY_ROOT(fa_pos) AS root_fa_pos,
  fa, 
  fa_pos, 
  verurs, 
  verurs_pos
FROM beispiel
CONNECT BY PRIOR fa = verurs AND PRIOR auftrag = auftrag
ORDER SIBLINGS BY verurs_pos, fa_pos;
```

Add `CONNECT_BY_ROOT(fa) AS root_fa` and `CONNECT_BY_ROOT(fa_pos) AS root_fa_pos` to capture the root values for `fa` and `fa_pos` for each branch in the hierarchical structure.

The `CONNECT BY` clause is modified to include `AND PRIOR auftrag = auftrag` to ensure that the hierarchy is connected based on the `auftrag` column as well. This way, each branch will only contain values related to the same `auftrag`.

Use the `ORDER SIBLINGS BY` clause to specify the order of siblings in the hierarchy. In this case, we order them first by `verurs_pos` and then by `fa_pos`.

With these modifications, you should get the desired ordered result without duplicates, and the tree structure will represent the Child -> Parent -> Grandparent relationship based on `fa` and `verurs` columns within the same `auftrag`.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I get it, but my code looks a little bit "crazy".  Can I do all these steps in one SELECT?

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT LEVEL
        ,CONNECT_BY_ISLEAF leaf
        ,CONNECT_BY_ISCYCLE cycle
        ,CONNECT_BY_ROOT(fa) AS root_fa
        ,CONNECT_BY_ROOT verurs AS verurs_top
        ,SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH(fa, "/") AS pfad
        ,*
    FROM (
        SELECT fa || "-" || fa_pos AS fa_ID
            ,verurs || "-" || verurs_pos AS verurs_ID
            ,*
        FROM beispiel
        ORDER BY verurs_id
            ,fa_id ASC
        ) connect BY nocycle PRIOR fa_id = verurs_id
    ORDER siblings BY fa_id
        ,verurs ASC
    )
WHERE root_fa = (
        SELECT min(fa)
        FROM beispiel
        )
```